# Symfony2: DateTime and form validation

Tags: php, validation, symfony, datetime

I need to know whats the usual way to handle datetime via forms.

I have a property in my entity like

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="founded", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $founded;
```

Then i render the form via FormTypes

```
->add('founded', 'date', array('widget' => 'single_text', 'format' => 'dd.MM.yyyy'))
```

The user then inputs a string like 01.01.1892
And sends it to the server via ajax:

```
form_team[basicdata][founded]:01.01.1914
```

In the controller i process the data and validate it:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new TeamsType(), $team);
$form->submit($this->getRequest()->request->get($form->getName()));

if ($form->isValid()) {
...
```

The thing is, that validation allways fails with: This value is not valid.
I guess a datetime object is expected, but the client just delivers a string.

How is that workflow supposed to be working? Please help me with that :)

Comment: I think you should use datatransformer to transform the client data to datetime. see http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html

Comment: i guess this is a day to day issue. how is it normaly done? there should be already solutions for this i think... ?

Comment: I need to know what the validation needs to get her. i cant the hell figure it out what is the client supposed to send. its impossible to send 01.01.1893 for example, i allways get "This value is not valid." i have no clue where the error is throwen and what it expects to get to not throw that error....

Answer (score 1):

`@Benjamin Lazarecki` is right.

You need to transform the string data (comming from within your form) to `DateTime` object. However, that transformer has been already implemented here:

http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataTransformer/DateTimeToStringTransformer.html

So, you can just and plug 'n' play it ;)

Comment: Is this the usual way? I dont get it why i have to transform the object manually when i use the form component, isnt it supposed to handeled automatically buy the framework? i guess its a usual usecase to render a datetime property of an entity in a forminput and process it back to server. i can configure the 'input' => 'datetime' parameter in the formtype, so i guess it should be handeled automatically

Comment: You have to use transformer because you have change the widget.